# Given are the Various Ways to return an object in C++, what are the potential Issues with each of these return statements

Tags: c++, c++11, return, return-value-optimization

Below is the code which has various return statements and all are working perfectly fine.
Compiler throws the warning for fun_ret_obj1

> Test.cpp: In function ‘myClass& fun_ret_obj1()’:
>   Test.cpp:45: warning: reference to local variable ‘myObj’ returned

But still the output seems to be fine.Is it by Chance?
Are there any catches with any of the return statements below?
Explanation would be really helpful, Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;


 class myClass {
 public:
 int a ;
 myClass()
 {
   a = 10;
 }
 };
 myClass& fun_ret_add()
 {
    myClass *ptr = new myClass();
    return *ptr;
 }

 myClass* fun_ret_ptr()
 {
     myClass *ptr = new myClass();
     return ptr ;
 }

 myClass fun_ret_obj()
 {
     myClass myObj;
     return myObj;
 }

 myClass& fun_ret_obj1()
 {
     myClass myObj;
     return myObj;
 }


 int main()
 {
     myClass obj,obj1;
     std::cout <<"In Main \n";

     myClass *a = fun_ret_ptr();
     std::cout<<a->a<<"\n";

     myClass &b = fun_ret_add();
     std::cout<<b.a<<"\n";

     myClass c = fun_ret_obj();
     std::cout<<c.a<<"\n";

     myClass d = fun_ret_obj1();
     std::cout<<d.a<<"\n";

 }
```

Comment: Listen to your compiler, don't do that!

Comment: "wrong" is only `fun_ret_obj1`. the warning there is right and the code just works by accident. It should look different if you set `a` to another value in the destructor

Comment: You're also leaking memory after you're done with `a` and `b`. You need `delete a;` and super weird `delete &b;`. Avoid such code. If pointer - smart pointer. Otherwise, return by value.

Answer (score 13):

First one is a memory leak:

```
myClass& fun_ret_add()
 {
    myClass *ptr = new myClass();
    return *ptr;
 }
```

Second one returns a raw pointer (evil - return a std::unique_ptr)

```
 myClass* fun_ret_ptr()
 {
     myClass *ptr = new myClass();
     return ptr ;
 }
```

Third one is perfect - returns a copy, which will almost always be elided. <strike>In c++17 it's guaranteed to be elided</strike>. This is efficient and safe.

```
 myClass fun_ret_obj()
 {
     myClass myObj;
     return myObj;
 }
```

*update*

In c++17 you could guarantee the elision of the copy this way:

```
 myClass fun_ret_obj()
 {
     return myClass{};
 }
```

*end of update*

Fourth one is undefined behaviour. Returning a reference to a non-existent object. Never do this.

```
 myClass& fun_ret_obj1()
 {
     myClass myObj;
     return myObj;
 }
```

#### regarding memory leaks

It is true that in the first example, a caller *could* release the memory if he/she knew that myClass had been allocated with `new`:

```
auto& x = fun_ret_add();    // a
...
delete std::addressof(x);   // b
```

This would require:

1. That the caller *knows* that fun_ret_add() is implemented in terms of new.
2. That the implementation of fun_ret_add() never changes
3. That no exceptions occur between (a) and (b)

The second example is similar. In this case, at least there is a hint that the object needs to be deleted, but the caller must still *know* that the object has been allocated with `new`, and he must guard against exceptions.

Contrast with this:

```
std::unique_ptr<myClass> fun_ret_ptr()
{
    return std::make_unique<myClass>();
    // or
    return { new myClass() };
    // or
    return std::unique_ptr<myClass>(new myClass());
}
```

Now the caller receives a smart pointer. If the caller does nothing but use this pointer, the myClass object will be properly deleted when the pointer goes out of scope, and all memory will be reclaimed.

Comment: There's zero difference between memory leaking in the first and second case. Nothing prevents you from doing `delete &fun_ret_add()`, after all.

Comment: @Richard Hodges , would you please explain memory  leak, it seems to be working fine at the moment, Also the second one is fine, where could things go wrong, what situations? Appreciate your commets

Comment: @Richard Hodges  : In the first example, we are actually returning the object (*ptr) and its pointer goes out of scope after the function call which leads to leak  and  in main  the reference of that object is used . Am i correct? 
Why is it not the right practice ?

Comment: @LearningCpp the memory leak occurs because the caller requires special knowledge in order to free the object and its memory (see addendum). It it not good practice precisely because it requires the caller to have special knowledge. Function interfaces should be intuitive and automatically support RAII without any effort on the part of the caller.

Comment: @dyp ok, thanks. That makes sense. It would be impossible to do in the case of `Foo a, b; return condition() ? a : b;`

Answer (score 2):

```
 myClass& fun_ret_obj1()
 {
     myClass myObj;
     return myObj;
 }
```

This creates a local variable on the stack, `myObj`. And returns a reference to that object. Then the object is destroyed because of it's scope. The moment the caller sees the reference it's referencing a stack object that has been destroyed, using it is undefined behaviour. And thus your compiler warns you about that.

Answer (score 2):

OK some explanations:

```
 myClass fun_ret_obj()
 {
     myClass myObj;
     return myObj;
 }
```

This one simply calls a copy-constructor. Nothing really special here.

```
 myClass* fun_ret_ptr()
 {
     myClass *ptr = new myClass();
     return ptr ;
 }
```

This one returns a pointer to a heap allocated object. It will **never** be deleted until you manually delete it. But it's safe to return.

```
 myClass& fun_ret_add()
 {
    myClass *ptr = new myClass();
    return *ptr;
 }
```

This one will return a reference to the value. While this is OK. You can not access the pointer `ptr` anymore and thus not delete the object manually. (OK you still could delete the object but you have to know later that this object was initially created on the heap and not on the stack to not cause any strange errors elsewhere. So this is likely to not get deleted later)

```
 myClass& fun_ret_obj1()
 {
     myClass myObj;
     return myObj;
 }
```

This one is **critical**. The moment the function goes out of scope the destructor will be called. (if you set a to a invalid value in the destructor you will see this).

Because the computer is "smart" and just says "this memory can be overwritten when needed" it gets not "deleted" (the destructor gets called though just not the memory location invalidated). So directly accessing the memory afterwards results in what seems like valid behavior. But this is just by **accident**. When you would initialize some variables or have some memory allocations on the stack this would get overwritten and you access strange memory. That's why this is undefined behavior and the compiler warns you here.

Comment: Yeah thats why I did not write "never" but while possible it's unlikely to be used that way.

Comment: Well... yes. But unlikely to do for beginners, who stumble across this question (and not very maintainable for the code too). Added though a mention, that you theoretically could.

Answer (score 1):

It's by chance. Your compiler doesn't lie.

Here:

```
myClass& fun_ret_obj1() {
    myClass myObj;
    return myObj;
}
```

You are returning a reference to an object that is going to be destroyed.
You are going to face what is called *undefined behavior*, it could either works or not.
In your case:

> the output seems to be fine

And it's by chance, of course.

Answer (score 0):

> myClass fun_ret_obj()
>   {
>       myClass myObj;
>       return myObj;
>   }

Looks innocent enough, but under the hood will create two temporaries (invoking the ctor on each, which propagates to ctors of all member objects, and so on...). Then when returning will copy the first temporary to the other before deleting it (invokes its dtor and the dtor of all member objects, and so on...), will then invoke the copy ctor (or assignment operator and those of its member objects, and so on...) for the receiving object in the caller, then delete the second temporary (invoking the dtor and the dtor of all member objects, etc...). Even if myClass and of its all member objects have implemented move semantics this may actually be a very heavy duty operation. Better to pass a reference parameter to the receiving object and perhaps use a POD sentinel (success/fail) as the function return type, or use std::unique_ptr as described perfectly by Richard.